# Go: Choose Go Environment resulted in error "command go.environment.choose" not found

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm writing go code in VS Code (1.74.3), with Go Team at Google's Go extension v0.37.1

I have five different projects and I'm trying to make sure they all function the same way.
They all exist in WSL on my Windows machine, same instance of WSL for each, under the same parent folder.

Two of the projects work as expected - I was able to set a GO Path for them and the Go extension functions work as expected.

For the other three projects, the GO extension doesn't work - the linting and formatting never happens.   In troubleshooting, I went to the command pallette to check the go path with:

```
GO: Choose Go Environment
```

When I try that in the three non-working projects, I get an error:

```
Command 'Go: Choose Go Environment' resulted in an error (command 'go.environment.choose' not found)
```

The odd thing is each of these projects are in the same instance of VS Code, so the configs are the same, extension version the same.  Any suggestions on what to check?

I tried another thing, by disabling the extension, opening Help > Developer Tools, then re-enabling it, and I'm getting an error logged:

```
Activating extension 'golang.go' failed: spawn EFAULT.
```

Comment: I was able to get this to work for me, although I'm still not entirely sure why it worked for some environments, but not others.  There was a line in my .bash_profile (runs when bash runs) that executed another command to run a shell environment for brew.
Once I removed that, it was able to find the right Go path and use the extension.